# No authoring in network using custom keys, a local Rococo chain specification, and a modified substrate-parachain-template

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, grandpa, aura

I have read through the documentation on `Substrate.io` and have created a network of nodes in both a relay and parachain with custom keys. The network is running in Kubernetes (I would like to have full control of the pods and therefore decided not to go with Zombienet after facing some issues with it) and the nodes are peering, but not authoring any blocks.

I am using a fork of the Polkadot `v0.9.37` branch (without any changes) and a parachain built using the [substrate-parachain-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template) (modified to use `v0.9.37` versions of the Substrate dependencies) with changes to the `template` pallet and custom RPC endpoints.

I used the `rococo-local` as the foundation for my relay chain and the `local-testnet` (renamed it to `energy-testnet`) for my parachain.

Log from parachain boot node:

```
2023-04-13 07:04:57 Parachain Collator Template
2023-04-13 07:04:57 ✌️version 0.1.0-faec041209f
2023-04-13 07:04:57 ❤️by Anonymous, 2020-2023
2023-04-13 07:04:57  Chain specification: Local Testnet 
2023-04-13 07:04:57 Node name: energy-boot-node
2023-04-13 07:04:57  Role: AUTHORITY
2023-04-13 07:04:57  Database: RocksDb at /config/node/chains/energy_testnet/db/full
2023-04-13 07:04:57 ⛓Native runtime: energychain-parachain-1 (energychain-parachain-0.tx1.au1)
2023-04-13 07:05:00 Parachain id: Id(1000)
2023-04-13 07:05:00 Parachain Account: 5Ec4AhPZk8STuex8Wsi9TwDtJQxKqzPJRCH7348Xtcs9vZLJ 2023-04-13 07:05:00 Parachain genesis state: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c98e1a39ca632a5836ccb914d2e3bc0fabe6246265025afa5a102bb29750206e03170a2e7597b7b7e3d84c05391d139a62b157e78786d8c082f29dcf4c11131400
2023-04-13 07:05:00 Is collating: yes 
2023-04-13 07:05:02 [Parachain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xc98e…206e, header-hash: 0xea88…7edd)
2023-04-13 07:05:06 [Relaychain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x3867…dcb5, header-hash: 0x3715…6934)
2023-04-13 07:05:07 [Relaychain]  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain] Local node identity is: 12D3KooWSbRiHWMGXznDBD5SBWGDAEnCw4JHwfKFgHMEf87gcpHj
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Operating system: linux 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  CPU architecture: x86_64
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Target environment: gnu 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz 2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  CPU cores: 4
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Memory: 15721MB 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Linux distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Virtual machine: no 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Highest known block at #0 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9616
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9934, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain] Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9977, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*","https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  CPU score: 333.41 MiBs
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Memory score: 9.14 GiBs 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 113.87 MiBs 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 58.94 MiBs 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain] Starting with an empty approval vote DB. 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain] Local node identity is: 12D3KooWJvrd6tfTbU33MnB8dyyW2iErNtvnKNyNYYWe7EzSqMU4
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Operating system: linux
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  CPU architecture: x86_64 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Target environment: gnu
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Memory: 15721MB
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Linux distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Virtual machine: no 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Highest known block at #0 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 0.0.0.0:9615
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain] Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=0.0.0.0:9933, allowed origins=["*"]
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain] Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944, allowed origins=["*"]
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  CPU score: 333.41 MiBs
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Memory score: 9.14 GiBs 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Disk score (seq. writes): 113.87 MiBs 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain]  Disk score (rand. writes): 58.94 MiBs 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Relaychain] discovered: 12D3KooWJvrd6tfTbU33MnB8dyyW2iErNtvnKNyNYYWe7EzSqMU4 /ip4/10.244.1.4/tcp/30333 
2023-04-13 07:05:10 [Parachain] discovered: 12D3KooWSbRiHWMGXznDBD5SBWGDAEnCw4JHwfKFgHMEf87gcpHj /ip4/10.244.1.4/tcp/30343/ws 
2023-04-13 07:05:14 Accepting new connection 1/100 
2023-04-13 07:05:15 [Relaychain]  Idle (3 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 5.1kiB/s ⬆ 5.3kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:05:15 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0xea88…7edd), finalized #0 (0xea88…7edd), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.7kiB/s
...
2023-04-13 07:05:57 [Relaychain]  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 3.5kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:05:57 [Parachain]  Idle (4 peers), best: #0 (0xea88…7edd), finalized #0 (0xea88…7edd), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s
```

Log from relay chain boot node (with the `-lparachain=debug` flag):

```
2023-04-13 07:04:38.439  INFO main sc_cli::runner: Parity Polkadot                             
2023-04-13 07:04:38.439  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ✌️  version 0.9.37-89e7646f52c               
2023-04-13 07:04:38.439  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023                   
2023-04-13 07:04:38.439  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Chain specification: Rococo Local Testnet
2023-04-13 07:04:38.440  INFO main sc_cli::runner:   Node name: relay-boot-node               
2023-04-13 07:04:38.440  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Role: AUTHORITY                          
2023-04-13 07:04:38.440  INFO main sc_cli::runner:  Database: RocksDb at /config/node/chains/rococo_local_testnet/db/full 
2023-04-13 07:04:38.440  INFO main sc_cli::runner: ⛓  Native runtime: rococo-9370 (parity-rococo-v2.0-0.tx18.au0)           
2023-04-13 07:04:43.800  INFO main sc_service::client::client:  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x3867…dcb5, header-hash: 0x3715…6934)                
2023-04-13 07:04:43.816 DEBUG main parachain::chain-selection: Using dispute aware relay-chain selection algorithm          
2023-04-13 07:04:43.819  INFO main grandpa:  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.                                   
2023-04-13 07:04:45.541  INFO main babe:  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.          
2023-04-13 07:04:45.549  INFO main sub-libp2p:   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWSB9qo3ecn3YGz2MsDKcG8SAp4c61RYTpN5vQDhBhr5xn                                   
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  Operating system: linux                      
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  CPU architecture: x86_64                     
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  Target environment: gnu                      
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  CPU cores: 4                                 
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  Memory: 15721MB                              
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic                    
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  Linux distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS       
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_sysinfo:  Virtual machine: no                          
2023-04-13 07:04:45.769  INFO main sc_service::builder:  Highest known block at #0           
2023-04-13 07:04:45.770  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate_prometheus_endpoint: 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615                               
2023-04-13 07:04:45.776  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]
2023-04-13 07:04:45.778  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*","https://polkadot.js.org"]
2023-04-13 07:04:45.779  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo:  CPU score: 805.37 MiBs       
2023-04-13 07:04:45.779  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo:  Memory score: 8.10 GiBs      
2023-04-13 07:04:45.779  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo:  Disk score (seq. writes): 132.13 MiBs                     
2023-04-13 07:04:45.779  INFO                 main sc_sysinfo:  Disk score (rand. writes): 65.58 MiBs                     
2023-04-13 07:04:45.794  INFO tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-voting: Starting with an empty approval vote DB.     
2023-04-13 07:04:45.795  INFO                 main babe:  Starting BABE Authorship worker                                                                                   
2023-04-13 07:04:45.800 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::pvf-checker: Examining activation of leaf 0x3715e8ad0100ec1d2cecc6f6441f6a8b5dffcf17e52d92c5b16e19e203216934 (0)
2023-04-13 07:04:45.807 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: New session detected session_index=0
2023-04-13 07:04:45.808 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::approval-distribution: Got new blocks []
2023-04-13 07:04:45.808 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: Determined past/present/future authorities authority_count=2                                    
2023-04-13 07:04:45.808 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: Issuing a connection request num=0                                                              
2023-04-13 07:04:45.808 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::gossip-support: error=NotAValidator                                                                             
2023-04-13 07:04:45.808 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::validator-discovery: New ConnectToValidators resolved request peer_set=Validation num_peers=0 removed=0         
2023-04-13 07:04:50.780  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0                                  
2023-04-13 07:04:50.794 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1681279490 min_ts=0 max_ts=0                     
2023-04-13 07:04:55.780  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0                                  
2023-04-13 07:04:55.795 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1681279495 min_ts=0 max_ts=0                     
2023-04-13 07:04:59.513  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sub-libp2p:  Discovered new external address for our node: /dns/relay-boot-node-service/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSB9qo3ecn3YGz2MsDKcG8SAp4c61RYTpN5vQDhBhr5xn
2023-04-13 07:05:00.781  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.5kiB/s ⬆ 1.5kiB/s                    
2023-04-13 07:05:00.795 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1681279500 min_ts=0 max_ts=0                     
2023-04-13 07:05:05.782  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s                    
2023-04-13 07:05:05.797 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker parachain::chain-selection: Prepared 0 stagnant entries for pruning up_to=1681279505 min_ts=0 max_ts=0                     
2023-04-13 07:05:10.783  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (3 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 2.0kiB/s ⬆ 2.0kiB/s
```

Log from second parachain node:

```
2023-04-13 07:04:52 Parity Polkadot                                                                             
2023-04-13 07:04:52 ✌️  version 0.9.37-89e7646f52c                                                               
2023-04-13 07:04:52 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2023                                      
2023-04-13 07:04:52  Chain specification: Rococo Local Testnet                                                
2023-04-13 07:04:52   Node name: relay-node-0                                                                  
2023-04-13 07:04:52  Role: AUTHORITY                                                                          
2023-04-13 07:04:52  Database: RocksDb at /config/node/chains/rococo_local_testnet/db/full                    
2023-04-13 07:04:52 ⛓  Native runtime: rococo-9370 (parity-rococo-v2.0-0.tx18.au0)                              
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.                   
2023-04-13 07:04:58   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWCdWwzXb4gEoGRYwbGwEVh2gcUaPP3qqSStNwZZYDhtgf             
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Operating system: linux                                                                  
2023-04-13 07:04:58  CPU architecture: x86_64                                                                 
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Target environment: gnu                                                                  
2023-04-13 07:04:58  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz                                            
2023-04-13 07:04:58  CPU cores: 4                                                                             
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Memory: 15721MB                                                                          
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic                                                                
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Linux distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS                                                   
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Virtual machine: no                                                                      
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Highest known block at #0                                                                
2023-04-13 07:04:58 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615                                            
2023-04-13 07:04:58 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]
2023-04-13 07:04:58 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"]
2023-04-13 07:04:58  CPU score: 879.27 MiBs                                                                   
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Memory score: 10.49 GiBs                                                                 
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Disk score (seq. writes): 126.21 MiBs                                                    
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Disk score (rand. writes): 50.08 MiBs                                                    
2023-04-13 07:04:58 Starting with an empty approval vote DB.                                                    
2023-04-13 07:04:58  Starting BABE Authorship worker                                                          
2023-04-13 07:05:03  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.5kiB/s ⬆ 1.6kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:05:08  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:05:13  Idle (3 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 2.3kiB/s ⬆ 2.5kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:18  Idle (4 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.8kiB/s ⬆ 2.2kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:23  Idle (4 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:28  Idle (4 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.9kiB/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:33  Idle (6 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 3.2kiB/s ⬆ 3.8kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:38  Idle (7 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.3kiB/s ⬆ 2.5kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:43  Idle (8 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.7kiB/s ⬆ 4.8kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:48  Idle (8 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 2.0kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:53  Idle (9 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 2.7kiB/s 
2023-04-13 07:05:58  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 1.5kiB/s ⬆ 3.8kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:03  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 8.1kiB/s ⬆ 3.9kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:08  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 1.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:13  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 3.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:18  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:23  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 1.6kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:28  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:33  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.4kiB/s ⬆ 1.6kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:38  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:43  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 1.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:48  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:53  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 1.5kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:06:58  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:07:03  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 2.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:07:08  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 5.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.9kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:07:13  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:07:18  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 1.1kiB/s
2023-04-13 07:07:23  Idle (10 peers), best: #0 (0x3715…6934), finalized #0 (0x3715…6934), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.8kiB/s
```

Three things I notice:

1. No *Epochs* are started
2. No print of `... ⏱  Loaded block-time = 6s from block ...` as shown in the "[Add trusted nodes tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/)"
3. The line `parachain::gossip-support: error=NotAValidator`

I have updated both chain specifications with the SR25519 and ED25519 addresses (each with 4 active authorities), added the parachain as an entry in the relay chain specification with genesis wasm and state, and used these specifications when launching the nodes.

Relay chain node flags (the boot node has `-lparachain=debug` instead of `--bootnodes ...`):

```
--validator --force-authoring --node-key-file=$(KEY-FILE)
--name=$(NAME) --base-path=$(BASE-PATH)
--port=30333 --ws-port=9944 --chain=$(CHAIN-SPEC-PATH) 
--bootnodes /dns/relay-boot-node-service/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWSB9qo3ecn3YGz2MsDKcG8SAp4c61RYTpN5vQDhBhr5xn
```

Parachain node flags:

```
--collator --force-authoring --name=$(NAME) --base-path=$(BASE-PATH)
--node-key-file=$(KEY-FILE) --port=30333 --ws-port=9944 --chain=$(CHAIN-SPEC-PATH)
--bootnodes=$(BOOT-NODE) --ws-external --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors=all --rpc-external 
--rpc-methods=Unsafe --prometheus-external
--
--execution=wasm --chain=$(RELAY-CHAIN-SPEC-PATH) --port=30343 --ws-port=9977
--bootnodes=$(RELAY-CHAIN-BOOT-NODE)
```

I have initialized keystores for all the nodes, but have left out the `--password-interactive` flag, due to the fact that I will only be running tests. Could this be the cause of my issues? Running the `author_hasSessionKeys` with the SR25519 public key returns `true`, but it might just check for the file and not whether it is valid?

Relay chain node keystore initialization (before the node is started):

```
./polkadot key insert --base-path=/config/node/ --chain=/chain-specs/relay-chain-spec.json --scheme=ed25519 --suri="0x$SEED" --key-type=gran
./polkadot key insert --base-path=/config/node/ --chain=/chain-specs/relay-chain-spec.json --scheme=sr25519 --suri="0x$SEED" --key-type=babe
./polkadot key insert --base-path=/config/node/ --chain=/chain-specs/relay-chain-spec.json --scheme=sr25519 --suri="0x$SEED" --key-type=imon
./polkadot key insert --base-path=/config/node/ --chain=/chain-specs/relay-chain-spec.json --scheme=sr25519 --suri="0x$SEED" --key-type=para
```

The main thing I want to avoid is using a UI for setting up the system, as I hoped to run tests on the network, making manual steps a drawback.

Hope that the information provided above gives an idea of my issue, otherwise please ask!
Thanks in advance ❤️

Answer (score 2):

For the next person facing a similar issue, I managed to get both the relay chain and the parachain to produce blocks.

It turned out that I had an issue with the initialization of the keystore of the relay chain nodes. After fixing that, I was able to produce blocks on the relay chain, but the parachain started displaying the warning: `Collation wasn't advertised to any validator. ...`.

I resolved this issue by adding three additional keys (`asgn`, `audi`, and `beef`) to the keystore of the relay chain nodes as described [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/how-to-properly-set-session-keys-for-relay-and-parachain-with-custom-keys).

I included the parachain in the genesis of the chain specification I use for the relay chain nodes according to the answer I got from @pepoviola to my question posted [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8027/is-it-possible-to-specify-parachains-in-the-polkadot-chain-specification-for-loc/8035?noredirect=1#comment8073_8035).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when I started with parachains, I solved the problem in following way:

- The account which I used on relay chain to register the paraId was same as one of the collators in the `customSpec` of parachain and after adding parachain successfully to the relay, it started generating blocks.

Comment: Did you perform the registration through an RPC call to the relay chain node connected to the parachain collator?

Comment: I used the polkadot-js explorer for the transaction.

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with the relay chain keystores and some additional keys that had to be added in order for the relay chain to start producing blocks and accept the parachain collators. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: Yeah there are gran, babe, imon, audi, para, asgn keys, if using rococo network beef key is also needed, sorry to mention in answer